# Is it possible to load a C binary-saved array into a Python array?

Tags: python, c

I have a file where I have saved C float arrays as binary data.
Is it possible to load this binary data into a Python list now?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my ignorance. I did try to search in various ways and formats 'how to read bindary array data from a file' but came out empty-handed

Comment: What, *exactly* do you mean by a "python array?"

Comment: What I mean is.. say we have a C array: float arr[]
We save that array into a file as binary data

Now in Python, we open this file, and read the binary data into an array
my_array = array_from_file()

Comment: @JackAvante that doesn't answer my question at all. *What **exactly*** do you mean by *array* in Python? Do you mean an array from the `array` module? Or do you mean a `numpy.ndarray`? Or perhaps you just meant a Python `list`? Generally, "array" in Python means a `numpy.ndarray` or people from some other language incorrectly calling a `list` an array. Rarely, but possibly, they mean `array.array`. So, which one do you mean?

Comment: Honestly, any one of these that allows me to turn it into a np.arrray().
But I see where the confusion is. I'll fix the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to do that using Numpy.memmap. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.memmap("filename", dtype="int32", mode="r")
```

Replace "filename" with the path to your array file and "int32" with the type you used in your C array.